# sourcetrail can't index "size_t" and several C++ standard library symbols

Tags: c++, compilation, stl

I'm using a software called sourcetrail to read source code. This software can index all the symbols in the source code and draw several graphs. However, when I index my source code, the software reports a lot of errors with the message:

```
unknown type name ''size_t''
```

I know "size_t" is defined in stddef.h, but the stddef.h file found by sourcetrail has empty content, it just has three lines:

```
#ifndef __always_inline
#define __always_inline __inline__
#endif
```

I don't know if I have set the correct include directory. The Global include paths of sourcetrail is auto detected from gcc, which is:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/backward
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include
```

I didn't set any compiler flags in the project configuration.
By the way, sourcetrail treated some "std::unique_ptr" "std::map" and "std::vector" symbols as plain text not template data types. I don't know if it caused by the failure to index "size_t"

Comment: Perhaps it would be more productive to open an issue on their git repo.

Comment: Yes, I have opened an issue on github